# Python - how to reuse a dataclass with a limited number of fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing

I have a dataclass with many fields and I need to use it in a test. So I decided to extend the class and initialize it with a limited number of fields needed for testing. But this results in an error when creating the test dataclass:

```
self.metrics_provider = TestMetricsProvider(data)
E       TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'class_name', 'type', and 'score'
```

**The base dataclass:**

```
@dataclass
class MetricsProvider:
    name: str
    class_name: str
    type: str
    score: str
    source: str
    location: str = DEFAULT_LOCATION
    algorithm: Optional[str] = None
```

**Dataclass in a test:**

```
@dataclass
class TestMetricsProvider(MetricsProvider):
    pass

data = dict(
    name="test",
    class_name="test_class",
    type="test_type"
    score="test_score",
    source="test_source")

class TestMetrics(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.metrics_provider = TestMetricsProvider(data)
```

Defining the test dataclass like below resulted in the error: `E TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

```
@dataclass
class TestMetricsProvider(MetricsProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

How should I properly create it in this case? Or maybe it has to be mocked somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your dictionary of values as keyword arguments (a.k.a. `**kwargs`):

```py
class TestMetrics(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.metrics_provider = TestMetricsProvider(**data)
```

The constructor of the data class expects the actual values of the fields as keyword arguments. When you use `TestMetricsProvider(data)` you pass `data` dictionary as the value for the first field `name`, making it similar to `TestMetricsProvider(name=data)`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Is it correct to leave TestMetricsProvider without an __init__ method, just go with a `pass`?

Comment: @samba Yes, you don't need to override the `__init__` method.